# How to get / use bufferstrategy in a Java applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, graphics2d, japplet

I was wondering how I would use something like a bufferstrategy in a Java Applet.

I want to draw something like an image

```
gfx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0, width, height, null);
```

to my applet but I am getting white flashes due to the graphics drawing to the screen not being buffered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have a thread that is repainting this image

Edit 2: The image is constantly changing so I need to repaint it each time it changes

Comment: Applets are dead - time to move. Swing components are double buffered by default, probably a better place to start (and yes, you can add Swing components to an applet)

Comment: This is a bit too broad for SO I fear, you are probably better off looking for a tutorial. There are a lot good ones out there. The basic idea is: You draw everything on a canvas and then draw the finished canvas to your screen. So instead of drawing the background and then adding every single element on top (which leads to flickering) only one image is being drawn each frame.

Comment: However MadProgrammer does have a point that Applets are definitely not the way to go.

Comment: You should also consider having a look at the [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as a starting point

Comment: I know applets are dead, but an applet is the only way I know to add a java to a website

Comment: @BlazingForrest Applets are dead, primarily because browsers have stopped supporting them, along with Flash (thank the developer).  If you really want to make games for the Web, then maybe you should look towards HTML 5 and it's support

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Applets are dead"* Absolutely agree. And given the the HTML 5 `canvas` & JS can replace most uses of rendering that might earlier be done in an applet, I think it's folly to try & get an applet working these days. **OP: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so the public void update(Graphics g) method doesn't have white flashes due to the graphics drawing to the screen not being buffered. But the paint method does. Odd.